# Has the player loaded the ad in their browser?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial

I have a game in which I would like to avoid spamming ads, therefore I came up with a creative solution, which includes me checking if any ad has been clicked(loaded into the browser).

`admobInterstitial.AdLeftApplication` would work fine if the user has choosen the "Always" option on the "Complete action using" menu list. Yet if not, AdLeftApplication is being called on opening the "Complete action using" menu list and this way the player can cheat and not actually load the ad.

**How can I check if the player has loaded the ad in their browsers?**